# Setting Active Solution Configuration on Visual Studio Mac 2019

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I am confused how to set the active solution configuration for Visual Studio Mac 2019.  Doesn't seem as clear cut as the Windows version?
For example - I don't want to build a copy of Windows projects in the solution so I made a Debug-iOS solution that only builds iOS plus the shared Core project.  But how do I make it active?  You will see in the list it says Debug is the active one "Debug (Active)".

[image]

I did not see in the documentation how to actually set the active one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/create-and-edit-configurations?view=vsmac-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/configurations?view=vsmac-2019

Also it seems VS Mac has the concept of Run Configurations which I don't think is in Windows... is this related?

Comment: The active configuration is the one selected in the main toolbar on the main IDE window. Run Configurations are used when running the application not building it.

Comment: thank you that makes sense and works.